# which java command should return custom java installation path

Tags: java, macos, java-home

I have jdk installed under "/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java"

When i do a "which java", it returns "/usr/bin/java"

But, I want which java to return /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java, instead of /usr/java/bin

How can this be done? and what is happening behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that /usr/bin/java is a symbolic link.

Try

```
ls -l `which java`
```

This will run an ls -l on the output of 'which java',  hopefully giving you the full path pointed to by the link.

Answer (score 0):

**/usr/bin/java** is a symlink:

```
/usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

If you use:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v
```

You can confirm whether or not it's using `1.6.0`:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```